# Example of a non-separating family of seminorms

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a real vector space and let $P$ be a family of seminorms on $X$. We say that $P$ is **separating** if for $x\in X$ with $x\neq 0$ we can find $p\in P$ such that $p(x)\neq 0$. I got no problem of constructing a separating family of seminorms. I want to construct a family of seminorms which is **not separating**. I tried but I can't. Can you please help me.

Comment: Do you know a seminorm $p$ which is not a norm? Then $P = \{p\}$ will do.

Comment: @Martin. I got it. Thx for the tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example is as follows: Let $X = \mathbb R^2$ and let $P$ be a family of seminorms which only contains the following seminorm:
$$
\Vert (x,y) \Vert = |x|.
$$
This is not separating as $\Vert(0,y)\Vert = 0$ for all $y\in \mathbb R$.

Here's an example where $P$ contains infinitely many elements. Let $X=C(\mathbb R)$, the continuous real-valued functions on $\mathbb R$. Let 
$$
P=\{\Vert \cdot \Vert_n \, : \, n \in \mathbb N\},
$$
where
$$
\Vert f(x) \Vert_n =|f(n)|.
$$

Comment: thank you very much for the two examples. Thumbs up!